# Copy all files from all folders Windows CMD

Tags: windows, command-line, xcopy

I have this structure in Windows Server:

```
PARENT DIRECTORY
├───DIRECTORY1
│       ├───FILEA
│       └───FILEB
├───DIRECTORY2
│       ├───FILEC
│       └───FILED
└───DEST_DIRECTORY
```

I want to copy only all the `FILE` from all `DIRECTORY` to another folder at the same level of `PARENT DIRECTORY`. I'm trying to use:

```
xcopy /s *\*.* ..\dest_directory
```

But it says:

```
File not found - *.* 0 File(s) copied
```

When I specify the folder of the `DIRECTORY` it copies normally.

Any help?

Comment: [for /d - Loop through directory - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)

Comment: there's the `tree` command in Windows that you can just run and copy the folder structure here. No need to draw

Comment: forfiles may actually be what you're looking for, given that you can easily specify the kind of mask as it traverses through a directory tree.

Comment: You mention that your files are called `FILEA`, `FILEB` (without a dot for the extension), and then you want to copy all files, called `*.*` (having a dot for the extension). Do your files have a file extension, in other words, do your files have a dot in their filename?

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following command in powershell:

Get-ChildItem -Path .\PARENT DIRECTORY -File -Recurse | Copy-Item -Destination .\PARENT DIRECTORY

Answer (score 0):

Using Powershell:

```
PS C:> Foreach($file in Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File .\) {Copy-Item $file.FullName -Destination .\dest_directory}
```

Using the classic way:

```
C:\> FOR /F %F IN ('dir /a:-D /s /b') DO ( copy %F .\dest_directory\ )
```